# Schengen and Canada - Order of obtaining Visas

Tags: visas, canada, france, schengen-visas, study

I am from India and I am going to start my undergrad degree in Canada this fall. Before going to Canada, I plan to stop in Paris for 4 days and then continue with my trip to Canada.

My question here is can I apply for the Schengen Visa while my application for the Study permit is in process? Because the study permit application can take some time and might not leave me with enough time to apply for the Schengen Visa.

My confirmed flight bookings are as follows: Delhi - Paris - Toronto - Stay in Canada for 3 months - Delhi. After that I'll going to and fro between India and Canada but I have no tickets for that as the dates depend on the uni's academic calendar.

Edit: I would like to add a few points and make my situation more clear:

- My application for the student permit in Canada has already been submitted and I have an automated letter from Canada stating the same.
- From my comment: I'll be a tourist in France and a Student in Canada. I don't have a study permit yet but I do have an enrollment letter from my University which states that I have enrolled in the university; the start dates of the program; and have made a tuition fee payment in the upwards of $40,000 and a Bank Account in my name which from which I can withdraw funds only after I'm in Canada (Guaranteed Investment Certificate)
- The only reason I am asking this is because the Schengen Visa application asks for the **Entry permit to the final country of destination (if applicable).** I have a confirmed ticket from Canada to India in december so shouldn't that make India my final country of destination? 
  Thanks

**UPDATE:** So, I finally decided to apply for the schengen visa. I applied for the visa on 26th June and got an approval the very next day. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: What will be the purpose of your visit when you apply for schenegen visa? I don't think they will give you schenegen visa on this behalf that you might get canadian study visa. So get first your study visa and then you can apply for french visa.

Comment: I'll be a tourist in France and a Student in Canada. I don't have a study permit yet but I do have an enrollment letter from my University which states that I have enrolled in the university; the start dates of the program; and have made a tuition fee payment in the upwards of $40,000

Comment: @TomasBy As a general rule Canada lets people keep their passports during the visa application process, and only requires it to be sent in when the visa is to be affixed.

Comment: @TomasBy The application for Canada is an online one and they ask for your passport only after they grant you a visa. Also that only connection between the two is the question in schengen visa form which asks about the permit to the final country of destination.

Comment: I think India would be your final destination if you already have the tickets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your passport, you *can* apply for the Schengen visa at any time in the three months leading up to your travel. But the application will be *stronger* if you wait until you have the study visa.

If you apply before you have the study visa, you'll need to convince the consulate that you *don't* have a plan B of "go to Paris, stay there illegally and look for work".

Perhaps, depending on your personal circumstances, it will be easy for you to convince them of that. (If you're in a position to drop $40,000 for a three month course of study, then it's probably not an attractive prospect for you to be an undocumented immigrant worker in Europe anyway). Or it is possible that your circumstances look so dodgy that you can't get a Schengen visa no matter what. Between those two extremes is a gray area were it can be advantageous for you to wait.

It is practically impossible to say with any certainty whether your circumstances fall into that gray area based on explanations on a site such as this. So it's a decision you need to make yourself. *In general* the advice would be to wait if you have time for it -- but on the other hand, the longer you wait, the more expensive it might be to change your flight bookings if you get *refused* by the French consulate.

Comment: I get your point and I don't think I can take the risk of a delayed student permit so I'm going to apply for the schengen visa now. Also I would like to clarify that the fees paid is  for the first year of a 4 year long undergrad program.Anyway, thanks for your reply :)